# Black overlay on image disable hover

Tags: html, css

I have a black overlay on the image and disabled image hover, I know it is stacked on the image but how I can solve this? I wanna hover the image and grayscale change from 1 to zero and overlay still there,  my code down below
thanks for your help.

```css
.box{
width:300px;
height:200px;
position: relative;

}

.image{
width:100%;
height:100%;
object-fit: cover;
filter:grayscale(1);
}

.image:hover{
filter:grayscale(0)
}

.black_layer{
        position: absolute;
    width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:black;
z-index:1;
opacity:.3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
<img  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616578738046-8d6bbb4ee28e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGFyY2hpY3R1cmV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="image"  />

<div class="black_layer"></div>
   
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `hover` on the image (what will never work because of the black layer on top of it), `hover` on the container `.box` and than target the content image:

```
.box:hover img{ .... }
```

(note: changed the backgroundcolor of the top layer to yellow to make the effect more visable)

```css
.box{
width:300px;
height:200px;
position: relative;

}

.image{
width:100%;
height:100%;
object-fit: cover;
filter:grayscale(1);
}

.box:hover img{
filter:grayscale(0)
}

.black_layer{
        position: absolute;
    width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:yellow;
z-index:1;
opacity:.3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
<img  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616578738046-8d6bbb4ee28e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGFyY2hpY3R1cmV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="image"  />

<div class="black_layer"></div>
   
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How had I not thought of that? thank you so much